# Responsibilities for a specific Experience on Careers is empty when I edit it

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

I have one Experience section where when I edit it, the Responsibilities field is empty. I tested this with the latest version of Chrome and Firefox, and the issue appears with both browsers. My profile is at http://careers.stackoverflow.com/pvginkel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the heads-up, would you please try it again?